# Uploading image to third party website

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am developing a website. The memory allocated for my website on the server is very less. So I cannot afford to save images uploaded by my website users in the space given by server.I'm trying for a dll or webservice which will save image in third party website like postimage.org

Comment: http://api.imgur.com/ seems fairly straightforward as well. I'm expecting a close on this though, since there's no correct answer to this: you're asking for opinions. You know what you need, go ahead and look for image upload APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try flickr's API? It supports uploading and is well documented.

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/

And there's a .NET library for working with it: http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/